# Image doesn't appear with THREE.js and Panolens.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, three.js

I am tying to get a 360 environement with some info buttons using the THREE.js and Panolens.JS

But I can't figure out why the image doesn't appear.

I keep getting the error: Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined.

Does somebody get where this problem come from ?

```html
  <body>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.122.0/build/three.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/panolens@0.12.1/build/panolens.min.js"></script>


    <style>html, body {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      overflow: hidden;
      margin: 0;
    }
    
   body {
  background-color: bisque;
    }
    
    #container {
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      margin-top: 10px;
      width: 700px;
      height: 400px;
    }
    
  </style>
    <div id="container"></div>

    <script>

var panorama, viewer, container, infospot;
var containerBaseWidth = 700;
var containerBaseHeight = 400;
var deltaSize = 100;

container = document.querySelector( '#container' );

panorama = new PANOLENS.ImagePanorama( 'https://pannellum.org/images/alma.jpg' );

infospot = new PANOLENS.Infospot( 350, PANOLENS.DataImage.Info );
infospot.position.set( 0, 0, -5000 );
infospot.addHoverText( 'TEST PANOLENS', 30 );
panorama.add( infospot );

viewer = new PANOLENS.Viewer( { container: container } );
viewer.add( panorama );

function changeContainerSize ( width, height ) {
  viewer.container.style.width = width + "px";
  viewer.container.style.height = height + "px";
  viewer.onWindowResize( width, height );
}
    </script>

  </body>
```

Comment: Thats a tricky one, looks like the error is coming from here https://github.com/pchen66/panolens.js/blob/3b047702970709951b9080d60010380071236849/build/panolens.js#L169 I think they're serving the project from a node server and thus process would be defined

Answer (score 1):

Theres a github issue on panolens' project documenting this: `Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined`

Opened yesterday.

https://github.com/pchen66/panolens.js/issues/340

Comment: Thank you, I do not think that is the problem as I am using panolens.min.js and the issue seems to be link to panolens.js..

Comment: I saw that the poster mentioned that it doesnt happen in the minified version but I tested your sample and it gets the same exact error.

Answer (score 0):

I could make it work by saving the raw code of panolens.min.js directly in my file and not with the url link ;)